Install pgRouting extension using Docker and enable it - Postgres 17
I'm trying to install pgrouting extension on postgres using docker.
Here is the complete dockerfile:
ARG BASE_IMAGE=postgis/postgis:17-3.5-alpine
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

LABEL maintainer="PostGIS Project - https://postgis.net" \
      org.opencontainers.image.description="PostGIS 3.5.1 spatial database extension with PostgreSQL 17 Alpine" \
      org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis"

ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 3.5.1
ENV PGROUTING_VERSION 3.6.2
ENV PGVECTOR_VERSION 0.6.0
ENV PGREPACK_VERSION 1.5.2


RUN set -ex \
    && apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        boost-atomic \
        boost-chrono \
        postgresql17-dev \
        boost-graph \
        boost-date_time \
        boost-program_options \
        boost-system \
        boost-thread \
        build-base \
        cmake \
        wget \
        boost-dev \
        perl \
        gawk \
        cmake \
        lz4-dev \
        openssl-dev \
        tar \
        wget \
        unzip \
        gdal-dev \
        geos-dev \
        proj-dev \
        proj-util \
        sfcgal-dev \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        cunit-dev \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gettext-dev \
        json-c-dev \
        libtool \
        libxml2-dev \
        make \
        pcre2-dev \
        zlib-dev \
        readline-dev \
        postgresql-contrib \
        protobuf-c-dev \
        postgresql-dev \
        zstd-dev \
        git

RUN wget -O pgrouting.tar.gz "https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/archive/v${PGROUTING_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/pgrouting \
    && tar \
        --extract \
        --file pgrouting.tar.gz \
        --directory /usr/src/pgrouting \
        --strip-components 1 \
    && rm pgrouting.tar.gz \
    && cd /usr/src/pgrouting \
    && mkdir build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
    -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/postgresql \
    -DPOSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/postgresql \
    -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/boost \
    -DPOSTGRESQL_SHARE_DIR=/usr/local/share/postgresql \
    && apk info -L boost-dev  # Verify boost-dev contents \
    && cmake -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/boost .. # Explicitly set Boost include dir \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/pgrouting 

RUN set -ex \
    && apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache clang llvm19

# Install pgvector
RUN set -ex \
    && cd /tmp \
    && git clone --branch v${PGVECTOR_VERSION} https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector.git \
    && cd pgvector \
    && export CC=gcc CXX=g++ \
    && make && make install \
    && cd / && rm -rf /tmp/pgvector

# Install pg_repack
RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache make unzip gcc openssl-dev zlib-dev lz4-dev readline-dev zstd-dev \
    && wget -q -O pg_repack.zip "https://api.pgxn.org/dist/pg_repack/${PGREPACK_VERSION}/pg_repack-${PGREPACK_VERSION}.zip" \
    && unzip pg_repack.zip \
    && cd pg_repack-${PGREPACK_VERSION} \
    && make && make install \
    && cd /tmp \
    && rm -rf pg_repack.zip pg_repack-${PGREPACK_VERSION}

# Install pgBackRest
RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache pgbackrest

# Cleanup
RUN set -ex \
    && apk del build-base cmake wget boost-dev git clang llvm19 postgresql-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN rm /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10_postgis.sh

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]

I don't get any errors and the image builds successfully. At entrypoint, I enable the extensions required using
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_tiger_geocoder CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS address_standardizer;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_repack;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgrouting;

But I do not see pgrouting enabled in the database, nor it is available in pg_available_extensions.
Is there a step I'm missing or is the Dockerfile wrong?
Kindly help.

You are probably running the CREATE EXTENSION statements in the wrong database.

I'm sure running it on the right one. Because '\dx' command returns other extensinos enabled like pg_repack (which also I'm installing as given in docker file)

ticing.pgrouting? Not sure what that is. Would appreciate if you could elaborate a bit on your answer.

Sorry. You probably didn't install the pgrouting software and the CREATE EXTENSION command failed without you noticing.

Alternatively you could use this image which has it installed already https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis

Please don't link to pastebins. The paste expires and the question becomes useless to future readers. Just include the Dockerfile in your question.
